# Remove outlier from five-number summary statistics

Tags: r, boxplot, tukey

How can I force `fivenum` function to **not put** outliers as my maximum/minimum values?

I want to be able to see uppper and lower whisker numbers on my boxplot.

My code:

```
boxplot(data$`Weight(g)`)
text(y=fivenum(data$`Weight(g)`),labels=fivenum(data$`Weight(g)`),x=1.25, title(main = "Weight(g)"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boxplot` returns a named-list that includes things you can use to remove outliers in your call to `fivenum`:

- `$out` includes the literal outliers. It can be tempting to use `` setdiff(data$`Weight(g)`) ``, but that may be prone to problems due to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) (and floating-point equality), so I recommend against this; instead,
- `$stats` includes the numbers used for the boxplot itself without the outliers. I suggest we work with this.

(BTW, `title(.)` does its work via side-effect, and it is not used by `text(.)`, I suggest you move that call.)

Reproducible data/code:

```r
vec <- c(1, 10:20, 30)
bp <- boxplot(vec)
str(bp)
# List of 6
#  $ stats: num [1:5, 1] 10 12 15 18 20
#  $ n    : num 13
#  $ conf : num [1:2, 1] 12.4 17.6
#  $ out  : num [1:2] 1 30
#  $ group: num [1:2] 1 1
#  $ names: chr "1"

five <- fivenum(vec[ vec >= min(bp$stats) & vec <= max(bp$stats)])
text(x=1.25, y=five, labels=five)
title("Weight(g)")
```

[image: basic boxplot with corrected fivenum labels]